# Pipenv install is not adding dependencies to Pipfile.lock

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, python-venv, virtual-environment

In the process of converting some projects which are currently managed by requirements.txt files to Pipenv. First, I make a Pipenv environment with the following:

```
pipenv --python 3.8
```

Activate the environment with:

```
pipenv shell
```

Install an editable package:

```
pipenv install -e [package]
```

The issue is that the Pipfile.lock is populated as follows:

```
"default": {
        "package_name": {
            "editable": true,
            "path": "./path/to/package"
        }
    },
```

The Pipfile.lock is meant to contain the information for **all** dependencies and subdependencies, such that once it is pushed to VCS, another person can replicate the environment, but this does not allow this to happen. I have tried using `pipenv lock` but it yields the same Pipfile.lock. All the dependencies show up on `pip list` and the constraints are visible in `pipenv freeze`. I have upgraded pip to the latest version as well.

Any suggestions on how to get the dependencies to add to the Pipfile.lock would be fantastic, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing on my end.
Doing `pipenv install -e ./sub-package` will properly install the sub-package dependencies.

However, doing a fresh `pipenv install` from the same project with the pipfile containing entry `sub-package = {editable = true, path = "./sub-package"}` will install the "sub-package" module, but not its dependencies. It seems like a bug to me!

Comment: What's more, the dependencies are listable using `pipenv run pip show sub-package` under the `Requires:` field.